# Regexp to find only inner p tags inside the p tags

Tags: regex

I need to find the p tags inside the other p tag. I just given below example to understand it better.

Ex:

```
<p><span>test12312312312312313131</span></p> <p><span>test12</span></p>  <p>Some text<p><span>test</span></p></p>
```

I need a regular expression to find the p tag inside other p tag.

In the above example the last p tag has another p tag inside. How can i find it through regular expression.

Comment: Try to avoid RegExp together with HTML. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: Answering the question: "By learning regex". Answering the broader question: "Do not attempt to use regex for this." Answering the meta-question: "Because you showed no effort of your own."

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: But i need to use regexp for this scenario as i am not using html parser.

Comment: @user3498863, as you can see, it is possible with certain types of regular expressions. It's just totally insane in most cases. The question is what tools and languages do you have at hand. It's not like you can do with arbitrary `re` engine.

Comment: @akostadinov, I am using java code to parse this with pattern and matcher class from java.uti.regex. And to find the regexp i am trying with  regex101.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your regex flavor supports [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), try something like this:

```
(?s)<p>(?:(?!</?p>).)*</p>(?=(?:(?!</?p>).|<p>(?:(?!</?p>).)*</p>)*?</p>)
```

This part `(?:(?!</?p>).)*` assures, that there's no opening or closing `<p` within. The positive lookahead at the end `(?=`... checks for being inside `</p`. See [demo for trying at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gG8lU4/3).

Generally regex is not the means for parsing html. What regex did you try and not work?

Comment: thanks @bobble bubble for your reply, i saw your expression in regex101. In the last p tag even  though there are mulitple p tags inside it is selecting  only one p tag  i.e last inner p tag in the main p tag. Regarding my regex i am trying to  find with regex101 to match my output.

Comment: Lets take an example `<p><span>test12312312312312313131</span></p> <p><span>test12</span></p>  <p>Some text<p><span>test1</span></p> test123 <p><span>test2</span></p> <p><span>test3</span></p> </p>` In the last p tag we had 3 inner p tags. As per my requirement i need to select all the p tags inside the p tag.

Comment: @user3498863 [Modified it a bit](https://regex101.com/r/gG8lU4/3), well that's why one should avoid to parse html with regex in many cases :)

Comment: thanks @bobble, Can you explain it how you had did it or refer me a link to read out about in deep about regexp.

Comment: @user3498863 Welcome! The positive lookahead checks for any character `(?!</?p>).`, that is not `<p` start/end or `|<p>`...`</p>`  another full p-tag. Explanation is at regex101 on the right side. For getting started see [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info) or [rexegg](http://www.rexegg.com/). Happy rexing :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it would be much easier to parse as xml. Java has built-in xml support or your middleware most probably has as well.

If you insist to use something else, you could loop through your string. When you find `<p>` then you increase index. When you find `</p>` then you decrease index. So when your index is `1` and you hit another `<p>`, then you know this is an inner `<p>` and you can put chars until next `</p>` into some variable (e.g. `StringBuilder`).

May `String.indexOf()` be your friend.